# Merge browser audio and microphone to pipewire sink

Tags: linux, audio, pulseaudio, pipewire

I want to create a custom sink via a bash script and merge my Firefox output audio and microphone into it.

To create the sink I use

```
pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=stream_sink
```

but I can't wire up the connections inside the script. When I use QjackCtl I can do this:

[image]

and it works fine.
How can I do this connection using a bash script?

I've tried

```
pactl load-module module-loopback source="RZ19-0229 Gaming Microphone Analog Stereo" sink=stream_sink
pactl load-module module-loopback source="Firefox" sink=stream_sink
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I don´t know how to do the connections in the script, but you can use the QJackCtl Patchbay. Configure your connections there by adding the sources and sinks en connect between them. Save that patch-config and tell Jack to use the saved patch-config on startup.

It might also be easier to create the sink in the pipewire config, so it is available after your system starts up. See the [Pipewire wiki](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/wikis/Virtual-Devices)

Success!